Model Splits in when in pose mode
Another issue that I'm facing is that I have done this rig to the best I can which I'm really happy about however, the model starts splitting in Pose mode. I have used a solidify modifier and applied it before rigging my character, and now when I move the players Arms it starts to split. What do I do to fix this issue?
Another thing is that the bones have dissapeared, and I am not sure how to bring them back.
I have my controllers there but not my bones.



hello, probably the solidify makes the automatic weights parenting fail? Could you please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/



Are you sure to need a solidify modifier to begin with? Is that thickness visible in the final render?

The weight is not correct, probably the thickness made the parenting With Automatic Weights fail, you need to correct it in Weight Paint mode.
You can see the bones if you reactivate their visibility in the Data panel, also activate the In Front option:

Now select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to Weight Paint mode, disable the brush Front Faces Only option:

Also activate the Projected option:

Select a bone with AltLMB and add (LMB) or subtract (CtrlLMB) weight where there should not be, for example the biceps should not be influenced by the forearm bone:

